# Swift UI button action function

Tags: swift, button, swiftui

I completely new on Swift, so excuse possible lack of precision. I am trying to build a login form that authenticates with a REST API.
Here is what I have so far following [this](https://blckbirds.com/post/login-page-in-swiftui-2-2/) tutorial.
My next step is understanding where to put all of the logic for submitting the form. I would like to extract it from the inline manner it is taking.

Can I pass a function to the action parameter? I tried finding some sort of extract feature on Xcode but couldn't get it to work (they are greyed).

```
import SwiftUI

let lightGreyColor = Color(red: 239.0/255.0, green: 243.0/255.0, blue: 244.0/255.0, opacity: 1.0)
let storedUsername = "john"
let storedPassword = "1234"

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var username: String = ""
    @State var password: String = ""
    @State var authenticationDidFail: Bool = false
    @State var authenticationDidSucceed: Bool = false
    
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                Image("logo")
                
                EmailField(username: $username)
                PasswordField(password: $password)
                if authenticationDidFail {
                    Text("Information not correct. Try again.")
                        .offset(y: -10)
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                }
                Button(action: {
                    if  self.password == storedPassword {
                        print(password)
                        self.authenticationDidSucceed = true
                        self.authenticationDidFail = false
                    } else {
                        self.authenticationDidFail = true
                    }
                }) {
                    LoginButtonContent()
                }
                
                
            }
            if authenticationDidSucceed {
                Text("Login succeeded!")
            }
        }
        
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct LoginButtonContent: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("LOGIN")
            .font(.headline)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .padding()
            .frame(width: 220, height: 60)
            .background(Color.green)
            .cornerRadius(15.0)
    }
}

struct PasswordField: View {
    @Binding var password: String
    
    
    var body: some View {
        SecureField("Password", text: $password)
            .padding()
            .background(lightGreyColor)
            .cornerRadius(5.0)
            .padding(.bottom, 20)
    }
}

struct EmailField: View {
    @Binding var username: String
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Username", text: $username)
            .padding()
            .cornerRadius(5.0)
            .padding(.bottom, 20)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an Object of your Model inside your Button's action, there you can execute your REST call and return a result to set a value to authenticationDidSucceed, so that the UI is updated.

If the used class conforms to the ObservableObject protocol you can even use its published variables to automatically update the UI.